# Замедление тектса в Bash

Tags: linux, bash

Вчера нашел аргумент(?) для `echo` который замедляет каждую букву, хотел сохранить, а компьютер выключился (в истории не нашёл)

Comment: Вангую это был `echo \a`

Comment: У меня что-то не работает

Comment: поищите **там же** ещё раз. «там же» — это исходники либо программы *bash* (если речь была о встроенной команде *echo*, используемой по умолчанию), либо программы `/bin/echo`. (почему исходники, а не справка? потому что в справке таких секретов не пишут!) удачи в поисках чудесного грааля!

Answer (score 1):

может нужно чтото вроде этого:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# slowecho -- a bash script that echoes its argument one character
# per second.
#
arg=${@}
for (( i=0; i < ${#arg}; i+=1 )) ; do
echo -n "${arg:$i:1}"
sleep 1
done
echo
```

оформить как функцию и передавать необходимы текст ей на вход

источник: https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-875283.html